# How to fix date function for end of month in python?

Tags: python, datetime

This function is supposed to add days to a from_date, adding n-number of days (add_days) without counting weekends and Holidays (from my list), but to stop at the end of the month if the from_date day will exceed the current month.
For example if I print:

```
 print date_by_adding_business_days(datetime.date(2015,01,22), 3,Holidays)
```

will print: `2015-01-27`, that is good, works for holidays also.

If I will try :

```
 print date_by_adding_business_days(datetime.date(2015,01,22), 12,Holidays)
```

It will stop at the end of the month as I want : `2015-01-30`.

But if my `from_date` will be :

```
print date_by_adding_business_days(datetime.date(2015,01,30), 12,Holidays)
```

It will return None, instead of `2015-01-30` that I need.

My problem is when my from_date is the end of the month, my function will return None. I want to return that exact from_date if my from_date is at the end of the month(won't depend of how much days I want to add.
This is my function:

```
def date_by_adding_business_days(from_date, add_days,holidays):
    business_days_to_add = add_days
    current_date = from_date
    result = None
    _, days_in_month = calendar.monthrange(current_date.year, current_date.month)
    while business_days_to_add > 0 and current_date.day < days_in_month:
        current_date += datetime.timedelta(days=1)
        weekday = current_date.weekday()
        if weekday >= 5:
            continue
        if current_date in holidays:
            continue
        business_days_to_add -= 1
        result = current_date
    return result
Holidays =[datetime.date(2015,10,14),datetime.date(2015,10,15)]
print date_by_adding_business_days(datetime.date(2015,01,30), 12,Holidays)
```

[image: Calendar]

Comment: try `result = current_date` instead of `result = None`

Comment: @FullGrim Try to see my answer, and what will happen if the last two days in a month is not business days.

Answer (score 0):

You codes does not check the start date.

```
>>> # The last day in the month is not a business day so it should returns `2015-01-30`
... print date_by_adding_business_days(datetime.date(2015, 01, 30), 12, Holidays)
None
>>> # The last day in the month is not a business day so it should returns `None`
... print date_by_adding_business_days(datetime.date(2015, 01, 31), 12, Holidays)
None
>>> # The last day in the month is a business day so it should returns `2016-10-31`
... print date_by_adding_business_days(datetime.date(2016, 10, 30), 12, Holidays)
2016-10-31
>>> # The last day in the month is a business day so it should returns `2016-10-31
... print date_by_adding_business_days(datetime.date(2016, 10, 31), 12, Holidays)
None
>>> # Last two days in the month is not business days so it should returns `None`
... print date_by_adding_business_days(datetime.date(2016, 07, 30), 12, Holidays)
None
```

The solution `result = current_date` does not work as it will always return the start date although there are no business day.

```
>>> # The last day in the month is not a business day so it should returns `2015-01-30`
... print date_by_adding_business_days(datetime.date(2015, 01, 30), 12, Holidays)
2015-01-30
>>> # The last day in the month is not a business day so it should returns `None`
... print date_by_adding_business_days(datetime.date(2015, 01, 31), 12, Holidays)
2015-01-31
>>> # The last day in the month is a business day so it should returns `2016-10-31`
... print date_by_adding_business_days(datetime.date(2016, 10, 30), 12, Holidays)
2016-10-31
>>> # The last day in the month is a business day so it should returns `2016-10-31
... print date_by_adding_business_days(datetime.date(2016, 10, 31), 12, Holidays)
2016-10-31
>>> # Last two days in the month is not business days so it should returns `None`
... print date_by_adding_business_days(datetime.date(2016, 07, 30), 12, Holidays)
2016-07-30
```

I have rewritten your code so it check the start date and will return the none in the absence of a result.

```
def date_by_adding_business_days(from_date, add_days, holidays):
    business_days_to_add = add_days
    current_date = from_date
    result = None
    _, days_in_month = calendar.monthrange(current_date.year, current_date.month)
    while business_days_to_add > 0:
        if current_date.weekday() < 5 and current_date not in holidays:
            business_days_to_add -= 1
            result = current_date
        if current_date.day == days_in_month:
            break
        current_date += datetime.timedelta(days=1)
    return result
```

-

```
>>> # The last day in the month is a not business day so it should returns `2015-01-30`
... print date_by_adding_business_days(datetime.date(2015, 01, 30), 12, Holidays)
2015-01-30
>>> # The last day in the month is not a business day so it should returns `None`
... print date_by_adding_business_days(datetime.date(2015, 01, 31), 12, Holidays)
None
>>> # The last day in the month is a business day so it should returns `2016-10-31`
... print date_by_adding_business_days(datetime.date(2016, 10, 30), 12, Holidays)
2016-10-31
>>> # The last day in the month is a business day so it should returns `2016-10-31
... print date_by_adding_business_days(datetime.date(2016, 10, 31), 12, Holidays)
2016-10-31
>>> # Last two days in the month is not business days so it should returns `None`
... print date_by_adding_business_days(datetime.date(2016, 07, 30), 12, Holidays)
None
```

Comment: Hello Diblo, thanks for your answer, thing is that I won't have any start date in a weekend nor in a holiday, this starting days are supposed to be work days, other than that I tested my function and it worked good.

Comment: Ohh I see - then the first solution works flawlessly :)